# Confused about Undefined Errors in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Apologies for the likely simple question. I have some React code that I would like to log my api response.
When I `console.log(this.state.api_response_name)` my console logs a response. When I try as below with `api_response_name.name` I get undefined in my console log even though there is a name field in my json. My question is why? I'm fairly new to JS and React, so sorry if this is a super trivial answer and happy for links to articles that do a good job of describing. I couldn't find any that made that much sense.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Form } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { api31Call } from '../helpers';

export default class PulseInputForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            project: "",
            mode:'view',
            api_response_name:{},
            loading:false
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.handleSave = this.handleSave.bind(this);
        this.handleEdit = this.handleEdit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }
    handleSave() {
        this.setState({mode: 'view'});
      }

    handleEdit() {
        this.setState({mode: 'edit'});
      }

    renderInputField() {
      if(this.state.mode === 'view') {
        return <div>working</div>;
      } else {
        return (
            <p>
              <input
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value="something else"
              />
            </p>
        );
      }
    }

    renderButton() {
      if(this.state.mode === 'view') {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.handleEdit}>
              Edit
            </button>
        );
      } else {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.handleSave}>
              Save
            </button>
        );
      }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({loading: true})
      // not_localized = hard coded project 
        api31Call('GET', '/projects','/not_localized')
            .then(data => {
              this.setState({
                loading: false,
                api_response_name: data
              })
            })
      }

    render() {  
        const text = this.state.loading ? "loading..." : console.log(this.state.api_response_name.name)     
        return (
        <div>
        <Form >
            <Form.Field>
                <label>Project</label>
                <input name="project" placeholder="Your Project" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </Form.Field>
            <Form.Field>
                <label>Timeframe</label>
                <input placeholder="Integer e.g. 50 (Max 90 Days)" />
            </Form.Field>
          {text}
          {this.renderInputField()}
          {this.renderButton()}
         </Form> 

        </div>
        )
      }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `console.log(this.state.api_response_name.name)`, try `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state))`. I'd be that the shape of the response is not what you expect. Please post console results above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The componentDidMount() method runs after the component output has been rendered to the DOM.(You could read about React lifecycle [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)) So, in the first render of your component there is nothing in `api_response_name` and the state is same you defined in the `constructor`. But after mounting the component in DOM, the function `componentDidMount()` is called and this code

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({loading: true})
    // not_localized = hard coded project
    api31Call('GET', '/projects','/not_localized')
        .then(data => {
          this.setState({
            loading: false,
            api_response_name: data
          })
        })
}
```

executed. So, after that the state change and you have the name in api_response_name. But, before mounting the render function called once and in this time `this.state.api_response_name` is equal to `{}`. So, you get an exception in this time and your component will crash. However, you could set `loading` to `false` in the constructor, then all thing is going to be okey. because, then in the first render `loading` is `false` and the text is simply equal to `loading` and after mounting `componentDidMount()` is execute and after api call your state change correctly and your component will work perfectly.

Comment: The order of operations piece was the key.